# php image uplaod show default image when image has not been uploaded

Tags: php, mysql, image, image-upload

In php I am doing a simple php image upload and showing that image in another page. For that I have my code is like this
For database I have my query like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'article` (
   `article_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `artile_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,    
   `article_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`))
    ENGINE='._MYSQL_ENGINE_.' DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8';
```

Now my form is like this

```
<form id="formID" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
     <label for="article_name">Article Name</label>
     <input class="text-input" type="text"  name="article_name" id="article_name" value="'.$value_test['article_name'].'" />
     <br/>
  </div>
  <div>
     <label for="article_image">Upload Article Image</label>
     <input type="file" name="article_image" id="article_image" value="'.$value_test['article_image'].'" />
  </div>
  <div>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
  </div>
</form>
```

My php code for inserting database values is like this

```
mysql_connect(_DB_SERVER_, _DB_USER_,_DB_PASSWD_) or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db(_DB_NAME_) or die( mysql_error() );
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
  "INSERT INTO `article`(`article_id`, `article_name`, `article_image`) VALUES ("","'.$article_name.'","'.$article_image.'")";
  if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $tmpName.$image_name ) ) {
     echo "Data has been inserted into database";
  } else {
     echo "error in inserting data";
  }
```

Here the values are inserting into the database easily and also the image is being uploaded easily.

My php code for fetching data from table (in another page)

```
<?php
   include '../config/config.inc.php';
   mysql_connect(_DB_SERVER_,_DB_USER_,_DB_PASSWD_) or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db(_DB_NAME_) or die(mysql_error());

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE `article_name`='".$_GET['loc']."'");  
   while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
      echo '<div>';
      echo '<img class="article-image" src="article/'.$row['article_image'].'" width="100px" height="100px" >';
      echo '</div>';
      $article_name = $row['artcle_name'].'<br />';
```

Here also I am getting the values easily(image and article name).
  When I am uploading one image and one article name is defined then it is showing in fetching page. But when one image has not been uploaded then it is not showing any image. I want that if one image has not been uploaded then it should show one default image and if image has been uploaded then it should show the uploaded image. So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

you could use [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php), like

```
if( !empty($row['article_image']) AND file_exists(YOUR_PATH . $row['article_image']) ) {
   //show your image from db
}
else {
   //show your default image
}
```